# Why is my listbox not resizing? (Dynamically resizing dialog components)

Tags: c++, winapi, modal-dialog, resize

My app is Win32; I'm using VS 2015. I have a dialog box that contains a listbox. I set the listbox to be dynamically resized, but it does not change when the dialog is resized.

Here are the listbox' attributes:

[image]

The listbox is owner-drawn:

[image]

This is the default size of the dialog:

[image]

This is what the dialog looks like when I stretch in Test mode in the Resource Workshop Dialog Editor. Notice the inside listbox expands too, exactly as hoped:

[image]

However, when it's actually running, stretching the dialog does not increase the size of the listbox:

[image]

Why is this not working? Is there some additional voodoo I have to invoke to get it to actually work? Does this only work in MFC? What is the Win32 equivalent of `CWnd::ExecuteDlgInit`?

Note: I have already looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270148.aspx and http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2015/07/27/dynamic-dialog-layout-for-mfc-in-visual-c-2015/, wherein I did not find an answer.

Comment: It only works in MFC. In pure Win32 you have to do it all yourself.

Comment: Really? Sigh... I know how to do this from scratch, I was just hoping to escape the tedium. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: There are many third-party resize/layout classes for Win32, I believe I had used a modified version of [this one from codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4985/Easy-dialog-control-resizer) for some time. Mainly I replaced `MoveWindow()` by [`DeferWindowPos()`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050706-26/?p=35023) to reduce flickering (make sure to also set `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` for your dialog).

Answer (score 2):

> Does this only work in MFC?

Indeed, this only works when using MFC<sup>1</sup>.

> What is the Win32 equivalent of CWnd::ExecuteDlgInit?

MFC is a library built on top of the Windows API. The windowing system in the Windows API does not provide any sort of layout management. If you want to see the Windows API equivalent, it's literally what is implemented in MFC.

So, why is this supported in the graphical resource editor then? Because that is where the layout information is generated. It's ultimately placed into a custom resource of type `AFX_DIALOG_LAYOUT`, where MFC picks it up to do its magic. If you aren't using MFC, that resource is simply ignored.

That's not to say that - in theory - you wouldn't be able to implement your own solution that reads the generated resource. As long as you can find documentation for the custom resource used by MFC. I didn't, but a look into the MFC source revealed, that it's pretty simple (a version `WORD`, followed by pairs of `WORD`s for horizontal and vertical move and size settings).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Or a library that understands the implementation details, such as the [WTL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wtl/).*

Comment: For anyone reading this - the functionality does not require MFC. The application does need to handle it, but you can use the Windows Template Library to do this (using the CDynamicDialogLayout class).

Comment: @fabspro This answer assumes that the question is asking about first-party support. For Windows' native windowing system, using C or C++ there are only two libraries: The Windows SDK, and MFC. Dynamic dialog layout is only supported with the latter. The final two paragraphs outline how this is implemented, and WTL's `CDynamicDialogLayout` implements just that. But then, that's a 3rd-party library, and I'm sure there are others that support this functionality, too.

Comment: But what does 'first-party support' mean to you? MFC is an application library published by Microsoft, as is WTL. I think it's fair to add the popular WTL option as a comment to your answer - you almost got there yourself in your last paragraph :)

Comment: @fabspro A first-party library is a library that's published by the implementer of a system (Microsoft in this case). WTL is not published, maintained, or supported by Microsoft. It is a 3rd-party library.

Comment: to be fair, it was originally published by Microsoft although the component that deals with dynamic dialogs was added later. It is disingenuous for you to call it a 3rd-party library. It was an internal library used at Microsoft which was open-sourced and has been subsequently improved.

Comment: @fabspro Not sure where you're trying to go with this. WTL has never been supported by Microsoft. The library has never been published by Microsoft. For all intents and purposes, this makes it a 3rd-party library. Regardless, I left a footnote, if only for folks that don't understand or care about licensing.

Comment: not sure what you're trying to say calling it not 'first party' either to be honest - it was published by Microsoft, remains under the Microsoft Public Licence and was supported by a Microsoft employee. To you, what does 'first party' mean? Is this just a language barrier between us?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is also supported in Windows Template Library!
https://sourceforge.net/p/wtl/git/ci/master/tree/Include/atlframe.h

If you have a look at the CDynamicDialogLayout class you can see how it works, and if you are using WTL you can even use the functionality yourself.

Answer (score -1):

For the record, I was looking for the solution to this as well, when I resized a control on my dialog all of the dynamic resizing stopped working, although it worked fine in the Test Mode.

To fix it, in the the second link you posted there's a section on adding a function: 
void CMFCDynLayoutDemoDlg::SetupDynamicLayout()

Where you re-setup the Dynamic Layout manager

Once I did this, it started working in the live version for me.

Very similar answer is in this post too:

[Recalculate dynamic layout properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004054/recalculate-dynamic-layout-properties)

Comment: This answer doesn't apply because OP isn't using MFC.