# Customising a dynamic layout at runtime based on control visibility

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have a multi-purpose `CDialog` that supports **resizing**. It can display content in 3 variations.

Variation 1:

[image: Variation 1]

Variation 2:

[image: Variation 2]

Variation 3:

[image: Variation 3]

The dialogue controls are using the dynamic layout settings from the resource editor.

Variation 1 is fine and need no changes.

Variation 2 does not display the combo and date button. As a result I would like the "Text will ..." label to be down at the bottom and the "edit" box to be taller.

Variation 3 has a similar issue where the date button should move to the bottom and the edit box be taller.

Can this be achieved by changing the dynamic layout in code?

## Update

I tried this in `OnInitDialog`:

```
if (!m_bShowWeekCombo)
{
    CRect rctCombo;
    m_cbWeek.GetWindowRect(rctCombo);
    ScreenToClient(rctCombo);

    CRect rctNote;
    m_staticInfo.GetWindowRect(rctNote);
    ScreenToClient(rctNote);

    m_staticInfo.MoveWindow(rctCombo.left, rctCombo.top, rctNote.Width(), rctNote.Height());
}
```

At first I thought it was working:

[image: Example]

The note is now at the bottom. But as soon as I resize the window:

[image: Example 2]

The note has reverted to the original position.

I know I have this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004054/recalculate-dynamic-layout-properties) to a similar issue but do I really have to re-build the whole layout?

## Update 2

```
if (!m_bShowWeekCombo)
{
    CRect rctEdit;
    m_editText.GetWindowRect(rctEdit);
    ScreenToClient(rctEdit);

    CRect rctCombo;
    m_cbWeek.GetWindowRect(rctCombo);
    ScreenToClient(rctCombo);

    CRect rctNote;
    m_staticInfo.GetWindowRect(rctNote);
    ScreenToClient(rctNote);

    //m_staticInfo.MoveWindow(rctCombo.left, rctCombo.top, rctNote.Width(), rctNote.Height());
    m_staticInfo.SetWindowPos(NULL, rctCombo.left, rctCombo.top, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    m_editText.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rctEdit.Width(), rctEdit.Height() + (rctCombo.top - rctNote.top),
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);

    if (m_pDynamicLayout)
    {
        if (!m_pDynamicLayout->HasItem(m_staticInfo.m_hWnd))
        {
            m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(m_staticInfo.m_hWnd,
                CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE(L"item already has dynamic move/size\n");
        }
        if (!m_pDynamicLayout->HasItem(m_editText.m_hWnd))
        {
            m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(m_editText.m_hWnd,
                CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE(L"item already has dynamic move/size\n");
        }

    }
}
```

When I try the above the control width is the original width, even though the dialog had restored to wider dialog width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CMFCDynamicLayout` reads the dialog resource, it stores the coordinates for the child controls as well as their dynamic resize/move properties.

This is all done in `CDialog::OnInitDialog`. If you move the child control, example, `m_staticInfo` then `CMFCDynamicLayout` doesn't know you moved/resized the control. So upon the next dialog resize request, `CMFCDynamicLayout` uses the old values.

You can add dynamic resize/move for all controls expcept `m_staticInfo` and other controls which you intend to move manually. Then add `m_staticInfo` separately:

```cpp
BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    CRect rctCombo;
    m_cbWeek.GetWindowRect(rctCombo);
    ScreenToClient(rctCombo);
    m_staticInfo.SetWindowPos(NULL, rctCombo.left, rctCombo.top, 0, 0, 
        SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);

    if(m_pDynamicLayout)
    {
        if(!m_pDynamicLayout->HasItem(m_staticInfo.m_hWnd))
        {
            m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(m_staticInfo.m_hWnd,
                CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        }
        else
        {
            TRACE(L"item already has dynamic move/size\n");
            AfxDebugBreak(0);
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Internally, MFC calls `LoadDynamicLayoutResource(m_lpszTemplateName)` to initialize dynamic size/move. But documentation says not to use this method directly.

## Clarification

If you are using a dialog that supports **resizing** then you must remember to calculate the new width and height when you move the control to the new position. You would then use one of the appropriate `Size` calls. For example:

```cpp
// The EDIT control height now needs increasing
iNewEditHeight = rctButton.top - iTextMarginY - rctEdit.top;
m_editText.SetWindowPos(nullptr, 0, 0, iNewWidth, iNewEditHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

It is up to you to workout how you want your control initially re-sized.

Then, in `OnInitDialog` I called a new method:

```cpp
void CEditTextDlg::SetupDynamicLayout()
{
    if (m_pDynamicLayout != nullptr)
    {
        m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(IDC_BUTTON_INSERT_DATE, 
            CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeNone());
        m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(IDC_STATIC_INFO,
            CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveVertical(100), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontal(100));
        m_pDynamicLayout->AddItem(IDC_EDIT_TEXT,
            CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));
    }
}
```

If you don't set the width correctly when using `SetWindowPos` and only use `SizeNone()` it will not resize correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this. What I had to do was re-compute the default size of the controls (since the dialog was resized) before I added them to the layout. Sorted.

Comment: I am not sure what solutions you came up with. I think you decided to move/resize all child controls manually!

Comment: No. Only the controls that I needed to resize. I just had to actually "resize" them properly first. EG: I had to change the width correctly when "moving" it to the right place. All the others are left as default via IDE resource properties.

Comment: Notice in your sample code you have SizeNone. That is no good. My controls are stretching either in width or height. But i had to change the base dimensions of the control first. So I had to re-compute the correct sizes.

Comment: I made tweak to your answer.