# MFC Dynamic Layout - Show/Hide Control and adjust other controls out of the way?

Tags: mfc

I'm Using the MFC Dynamic Layout for a Dialog and have a checkbox towards the bottom.  If this is clicked a new section shows between other controls (basically the other controls are moved down and the "inserted" controls are unhidden).  The reverse happens when unchecked (the "removed" controls hidden and the other controls are moved back up).

However, if you resize the dialog, MFC is not moving the controls by a delta amount and ends up putting the other controls over the top of the newly shown controls.

Is there a way to tell the MFC Dynamic Layout that a controls relative position has changed by some delta (X and/or Y).

TIA!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recalculate dynamic layout properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004054/recalculate-dynamic-layout-properties)